# Math book with Pretty boxes to frame the theorems Indesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, mathematics

> I would like to create math school book with Indesign CS6 which contain the pretty boxes to frame the theorems-lemma-proposition-etc to looks like that :

[image]

[image]

- I'm interseted about how to create the pretty boxes to frame the theorems with indesign not about arabic typesting

By the way i just started to learn about Indesign CS6 using ebook : "**Adobe Creative Team-Adobe InDesign CS6 Classroom in a Book-Adobe Press (2012)**"

**My attempts**

[image]

**Update:**

Thank you, i follow what you said and I succeed to create the **Rounded Rectangle Shape** Using `rectangle tool` and `gradient tool` but **Top Curved Shape** still difficult for me since i'm not familiar yet with `Pen tools` so could you elaborate more about that step Please

[image]

Comment: Hi Educ, can you tell us what you have tried to achieve the desired effect? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. These look like the use of several gradients and some minor drop shadows.

Comment: see my update please

Answer (score 4):

Let me preface this and say that GD.SE is not a site for basic software education or tutorials. The process for creating your example involves a lot of steps. I have briefly went over the process but there are plenty of tutorials that go indepth for each part.

**Top Curved Shape**

Choose the Pen tool (p). Start at the left side and make a point. Move to the start of the curve, left click and hold shift and move the mouse to the right. You will get to handles that come out. Move up a little bit and to the right and do the same thing (left click and hold shift).

To add a drop shadow. Go to Object -> Effects -> Drop Shadow.

[image: curves]

You don't have to worry about the rounded edges of the sides at this point. Finished the shape.

[image]

**The Gradient**

You first have to add each color as a swatch before you can make the gradient. You can use the eyedrop tool (I) or pick your own colors. At the top, click the arrow next to the swatch and then click add new swatch (Next to the trash can).

[image: new swatch]

Go to your swatches panel and click more options and then Create New Gradient Swatch

[image: Swatch options]

Choose liner and choose the different colors for the swatch. Apply that swatch to the curved shape.

**To create the Rounded Rectangle Shape**

Use the rectangle tool and create a shape. Apply a round corner.

[image: round corner]

Select the curved shape and hit CTRL/CMD + C to copy. Select the newely created rectangle with round corners and go to Edit -> Paste Into.

Apply a gradient to the rectangle shape as well. You can move the gradient placement with the gradient tool (G).

**Result**

[image: result box]

Comment: could you package your work and send it to me please to open up and work on it thanks

Comment: @Educ I did not save the working file for this. Sorry if this is harsh but I would not send the file if it was saved. I do not do work for free. This site is not for basic software education and your question was close to being closed as too broad. If you do get stuck, I will be more than happy to help but GD.SE is not a site for tutorials.

Comment: ok i see don't worry i'll try to learn how to do it thanks anyway